# How to find the 24 hours difference based on Trip booked time

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

From the API, I'm getting Trip booked Timezone(PST), Date-Time(2020-07-10 16:00:00). Now I want to check the 24 hours time difference with the user browser current time and display Cancel button otherwise, we need to hide the button. What I have done below is I'm passing trip booked time-`2020-08-10 16:58:00` and booked timezone-`PST` which is getting from API then I'm finding the `currentDate` and taking the difference using the `diff` method. But I'm not getting current values. Any Help?

```
const departureDateWithTimeZone = moment.tz('2020-08-10 16:58:00', 'PST');
const currentDate = moment().format();
const diff = departureDateWithTimeZone.diff(currentDate, 'h');
```

Comment: You still after a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Whats you expected output ? 24 hours ? from that time.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) state that the last argument in `moment.tz` should be a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Use `America/Los_Angeles` (or any other correct tz identifier) instead of `PST`:

```js
const departureDateWithTimeZone = moment.tz('2020-08-10 16:58:00', 'America/Los_Angeles'); 
const currentDate = moment(); 
const diff = departureDateWithTimeZone.diff(currentDate, 'h');
  
console.log(`Current date: ${currentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z')}`);
console.log(`Departure date: ${departureDateWithTimeZone.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z')}`);
console.log(`Diff in hours: ${diff}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```